# Not all the data on mongoose schema can be posted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoose schema as follows:

```
var myprojectsSchema = new Schema({

        pname: String,
        pnumber: String,
        plocation: String,
        pclient: String,
        clientabn: String,
        contname: String,
        contnumber: String,
        mobile: String,
        address: String,
        city: String,
        country: String,
        pocode: String,
        pdesc: String,
        punit: String,
        pqty: String,
        prate: String,
        pprice: String,


});

Myprojects  = mongoose.model("Myprojects", myprojectsSchema);
```

when I post the data from a form, not all the data can be seen on mongo database, I only can see the first 12 items on mongo database but not the last 5. please note i don't have the last 5 items on my form but still i should see them as "nill" on data, is it correct? (I have another schema exactly the same situation but can see all the items in schema)
below is the post route:

```
app.post("/myprojects", function(req,res){

var pname = req.body.pname;
var pnumber = req.body.pnumber;
var plocation = req.body.plocation;
var pclient = req.body.pclient;
var clientabn = req.body.clientabn;
var contname = req.body.contname;
var contnumber = req.body.contnumber;
var mobile = req.body.mobile;
var address = req.body.address;
var city = req.body.city;
var country = req.body.country;
var pocode = req.body.pocode;
var pdesc = req.body.pdesc;
var punit = req.body.punit;
var pqty= req.body.pqty;
var prate= req.body.prate;
var pprice= req.body.pprice;


 var newProject = {
    pname:pname,
    pnumber:pnumber, 
    plocation:plocation, 
    pclient:pclient,
    clientabn:clientabn, 
    contname:contname,
    contnumber:contnumber,
    mobile:mobile, 
    address:address, 
    city:city, 
    country:country, 
    pocode:pocode,
    pdesc:pdesc,
    punit:punit,
    pqty:pqty,
    prate:prate,
    pprice:pprice,
 };

 Myprojects.create(newProject,function(err, newlycreated){
    if(err){console.log(err);}else{
        res.redirect("/myprojects");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: You can set default values to ensure something is set if you don’t post data for a particular field: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no value is available for a property than that property is considered to be `undefined`. That's why you don't see that in mongodb.

you can use default value as follow:

```
pprice: {
   type: String,
   default: null
}
```

Comment: Thanks Farhad but I have another schema, quite similar and when I post the form with no value I still can see all the properties on mongo as the blank properties.l like property “”

Comment: @Sam if that form has properties and being posted then those properties are created. Try console.log on req.body on that form.

Also do share that schema to be able to better help :)